# Implications of Admin Consent for "user_impersonation" Delegated Permission in Azure AD for Yammer

Tags: azure-active-directory, yammer

I have an existing custom application that integrates with Yammer in Azure AD. Within this application, I utilize the `user_impersonation` delegated permission to get data posted on the Yammer network. Additionally, my application requests the `Sites.Read.All` permission to access SharePoint attachments shared in Yammer.
[image]

My current process involves:

1. obtaining an access token for `user_impersonation` via Oauth flow for user_impersonation
2. obtaining admin consent by directing administrators to the following URL: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e&state=12345&redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/permissions.`

I will be using this consent to later on get an access token for
`Sites.Read.All` via client-credentials flow.

However, I've noticed that when an administrator grants consent, it extends consent to all the permissions configured in the Azure AD app. I've recently found a v2 endpoint for admin consent where I can pass the list of scopes in the consent URL. While the delegated 'user_impersonation' permission suffices for accessing all the data in the Yammer network, I've noticed that with admin consent, it seems like I'm obtaining additional permissions.
[image]
[image]

Given this setup, what could be the implications of admin consent for the `user_impersonation` delegated permission within my existing custom app?

Answer (score 0):

I created an **Azure AD Application** and added API permissions:

[image]

To grant admin consent I used the below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id=ClientID&state=12345&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
```

[image]

The admin consent granted to the API permissions:

[image]

For **sample**, you can also revoke the admin consent for one API permission if you don't need it like below:

[image]

> **Note** that:  Admin consent enables an administrator to give permissions to an application on behalf of all tenant users.

- This means that if admin consent is granted for your application, the user who logs in will be able to access all the permissions that are configured in the application.
- The **`user_impersonation`** delegated permission enables the application to connect to the Yammer network on behalf of the user and access all the Yammer data.
- And it will also allow to access SharePoint attachments shared in Yammer as **`Sites.Read.All`** permission is granted.

**Reference:**

[Overview of permissions and consent in the Microsoft identity platform - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/permissions-consent-overview#delegated-access-access-on-behalf-of-a-user)